# Creating android app for existing project

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a project which is made using the Spring MVC + AngularJS.

So. consequently, i have a back-end API done and working in Spring MVC + Spring Security.

I want to make Android/iPhone apps for project (first - Android). I'm completely new to apps development.

**The questions are:**

1. Can i use the existing API, especially the user authentication which is done in Spring Security?
2. What is the right tools ? just Android SDK + gradle + make views?
3. Any suggestion, maybe i can get the simple app template which have a simple login function + any few API calls.

Answer (score -1):

1. you can directly use those APIs in android projects, i don't know about iOS.But i think it is possible to use same APIs in iOS app.
   2.You can use Eclipse or Android Studio for writing android programs. you can download sdk at the time of installation of setup file or else you can give sdk path at the time of installation.
   3.And coming to your third question you have server side code which is in angular.js, through which you can interact with android app. just build demo project with LOGIN details and use AsyncTask to interact with server. 
   Thanks .

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply but it doesn't really answer anything.
Server side code in AngularJS? what are you talking about?

Comment: 1. Yes , 2 you would do this as a rest flow andoid will require you to make rest calls of the main gui thread 3 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android/tree/master/spring-android-rest-template/src